# What is the correct way of coding this classes 'linked' to each other

Tags: python, class, oop

I have 2 classes i defined in this way:

```
def process_data(data):
    ### [...] here makes all the processing of the data
    return model  ## model is a class Model object

class A:
    def __init__(self, data) -> None:
        self.model = process_data(data) 
        pass
    def test1_on_model(self):
        ### run some tests and prints the results
        pass
    def test2_on_model(self):
        ### run some other tests and prints the results
        pass

class B:
    def __init__(self, model) -> None:
        self.model = model
        pass
    def test1_on_model(self):
        ### run some tests and prints the results
        pass
    def test2_on_model(self):
        ### run some other tests and prints the results
        pass
```

As you can see class A is simply starting from raw data to make a model object while class B takes directly the model object. I need those helper functions (`test1_on_model`...) to be callable on the instances of both class A and B.

I am sure there is a clean way to make it work, like using `super` or something else. But I am not familiar with it and so I cannot think of how to implement it in this case.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is here. Yes, `class A` has to make a call to get the `model` and `class B` has the `model` provided. In both cases your other methods will have access to it via `self.model`.

Comment: So the only difference between A and B is the way they are instantiated?

Comment: make be creatge a abstract class having tests and inherit it in A and B

Comment: Yes, 2 differently instantiated classes that give the user some helper functions. They both give info related to the `model` object but class A starts from raw data and class B takes the model directly

Comment: But what is the problem you want an answer to?

Comment: Clean the code, as you can see in the example I have to repeat twice the definition for the same functions. I still want them to be methods of class A and B so I cannot define them in the global scope and then just call `test1_on_model(instance_A)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use class methods:

```py
def process_data(data):
    ### [...] here makes all the processing of the data
    return model  ## model is a class Model object

class C:
    def __init__(self, model) -> None:
        self.model = model
        pass
    @classmethod
    def from_raw_data(cls, data):
        return cls(process_data(data))
    def test1_on_model(self):
        ### run some tests and prints the results
        pass
    def test2_on_model(self):
        ### run some other tests and prints the results
        pass
```

So you can create an object from a model (like class b) or like class A using `C.form_raw_data(data)`

Answer (score 1):

You can have a base class which contains the methods, but then have both A and B derived from it to get your two methods of instantiating a class:

```py
def process_data(data):
    ### [...] here makes all the processing of the data
    return model  ## model is a class Model object

class Base:
    def test1_on_model(self):
        ### run some tests and prints the results
        pass
    def test2_on_model(self):
        ### run some other tests and prints the results
        pass

class A(Base):
    def __init__(self, data) -> None:
        self.model = process_data(data) 

class B(Base):
    def __init__(self, model) -> None:
        self.model = model

data = ...
model = ...

a = A(data)
b = B(model)
```